# CSS flexbox responsive ui

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to design a page avoiding code duplications.

Basically, I have a page with a filter component on the left and results on the right with a summary header.

On the mobile, the filter component is inside the summary header.

Playing with the display property I can achieve that, but don't want to duplicate html like in the following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='d-none d-lg-flex col-lg-3'>DUPLICATED</div>
    <div style='background-color:darkslategrey' class='col-12 col-lg-9'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div style='background-color:red' class='col-3 col-lg-6'>counter</div>
        <div style='background-color:grey' class='col-4 d-lg-none'>DUPLICATED</div>
        <div style='background-color:green' class='col-5 col-lg-6'>sorting</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12'>results</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**It is possible to achieve the desired design with flexbox and bootstrap?**

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no way to do it using flexbox without repeating the markup. You should rather consider using grid layout.